# What does strcpy (p, p+1) do (being p an array of chars)?

Tags: c, strcpy

Eventhough I know what strcpy does I was unable to understand what it did in this specific case. Where I saw this it said that it copied the string p one character back, but I didn't fully understand why the source was p+1.
The code where I saw it is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINE 100000

int mgetline(char s[], int maxline);
int removetrail(char p[], int length);

int main(void){
    int len, lenr;
    char line[MAXLINE];

    while ((len = mgetline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0){
        if ((lenr = removetrail(line, len)) > 0)
            printf("%s", line);
    }
    return 0;
}

int mgetline(char s[], int maxline)
{
    int i, c;

    for (i = 0;(i < maxline) && ((c = getchar()) != EOF);++i){
        if (c == '\n'){
            s[i] = c;
            break;
        }
        else
            s[i] = c;
    }

    ++i;
    s[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}

int removetrail(char p[], int length)
{
    int a;
    for (a = 0 ; ((p[a] == '\t') || (p[a] == ' ')) && a < length ;  length--)
        strcpy(p, p+1);
    for (a = length - 2 ; ((p[a] == '\t') || (p[a] == ' ')) && a > 0 ; --a)
        ;

    if ((p[a] != ' ') && (p[a] != '\t') && (a >= 0)){
        ++a;
        p[a] = '\n';
        ++a;
        p[a] = '\0';
    }

    return a;
}
```

Comment: Looks like incorrect code to me. From the [strcpy manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html): `The strings may not overlap`

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour

Comment: It's technically undefined behavior, but more than likely it results in the first character of the string getting popped off.  E.g.  `"abc"` becomes `"bc"`.  If `p` points to an empty string, all bets are off, and the program state may be corrupted.

Comment: The safer approach would be to use `memmove`, which allows for overlap.

Comment: That code is just completely wrong. Not only does it violate the `strcpy` preconditions, it also uses the same value for `p` for every iteration of the loop when instead it seems is should be using the `a` index.

Comment: Rather than moving the whole string it is simpler to just advance a pointer and ignore the first character.  This is poor code.

Comment: @selbie idk about "more than likely" -- strcpy probably checks the length and calls memcpy,  and memcpy probably uses word-sized chunking or bigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably author of that codewanted do delete first char of the string. But it is a **wrong** code as source & destination must not overlap.

Another problem is if the string length is 0.

The correct version:

```
char *removeFirst(char *str)
{
    char *wrk = str;
    if(str && *str)
    {
        do
        {
            *str = *(str +1);
        }
        while(*str++);
    }
    return wrk;
}

char *ostrcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    size_t len = strlen(src);

    memmove(dest, src, len + 1);
    return dest;
}


int main()
{
    char str[] = "hello";

    printf("%s\n", removeFirst(str));
    printf("%s\n", ostrcpy(str, str+1));
}
```

Comment: What is the point of (a) naming an object `wrk` when it is not used for work, (b) moving the first character to the end of the array when that was not requested, (c) moving the first character by repeatedly swapping it between two positions instead of remember it once and writing it at the end once, and (d) using an `int` to hold `char`? Why not just write `removeFirst` as `if (str) for (char *p = str; *p; ++p) p[0] = p[1]; return str;`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil leftover. It was something else :). Why do not for loop - the answer is "because ....". There is no difference in the resulting code. So you like for I like while